# Using dynamic in C# without referencing a DLL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection

I want to use dynamic in C# to interact with objects defined in an external API (DLL). In such a way, I don't want to reference the API in my console app. Is this doable?

For instance, I used something as:

```
dynamic obj1 = new ObjectDefinedInAPI();
```

Compiler keeps on nagging that

```
The type or namespace name 'objectDefinedInAPI' could not be found ...
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Load assembly dynamically. Keyword `dynamic` just states that the member binding is deferred and will be done at runtime.

Comment: As @HamletHakobyan gave guidance, here is a [reference tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx). The assemblies you're interoperating with must be loaded into memory at some point. Think about the Windows API, you have to use `DllImport`; that loads them into memory.

Comment: For this, I believe you will have to resort to the ServiceLocator pattern and a library that contains an Interface for your service. This library must be common to both your Console Application and the library containing the actual implementation of your class that inherit from that Interface. You can then load the DLL dynamically and have it auto register itself in your ServiceLocator container.

Comment: Alternatively if you really don't want to load the dll, you can use `new ExpandoObject()` (which makes more sense than creating an instance of a type and assigning it to a `dynamic` field).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel How `ExpandoObject` will help? Op need to use existing class. It may have some good implemented functionality which OP may need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to NeutronCode answer, you can also try the following:

```
public interface IDynamicService {
    void DoSomething();
}

public void static main() {
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("filepath"); 
    var aClass = assembly.GetType("NameSpace.AClass");
    IDynamicService instance = Activator.CreateInstance(aClass) as IDynamicService;

    if (instance != null) {
        instance.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This way you can ensure your type will have a specific implementation. Please note that the actual class must inherit the interface in order for this to work, so if you don't have access to the other dll source code, this won't help much. The upside of doing it this way is that you get Intellisense and will always be sure that your dynamic class interfaces well with your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the assembly manually and then create a instance of a class given that you know the assembly name and class name.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("filepath"); 
var aClass = assembly.GetType("NameSpace.AClass");
dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(aClass);
```